# CSS Sprites, positioning is not working.

Tags: css, button, sprite

My 3 buttons underneath each other, however when i hover over the image in the browser, the bottom button disappears. Buttons starting from the top are normal button, hovering, and when the button is selected. Can anyone help to make my button similar to this, i used this code and it doesnt work still. Thanks in advanced! :D 
http://www.icondeposit.com/blog:custom-css-button-sprite

Button: https://www.dropbox.com/s/j9ecwlgqu8d5508/button-2.png

Here is my css code,

```
.GoogleMarker {
    width: 1086px;
    height: 1118px;
    background: transparent url(button-2.png) 0 0px no-repeat; /* When not hovered over */
}
.GoogleMarker:hover {
    width: 1086px;
    height: 1118px;
    background: transparent url(button-2.png) 0 -503px no-repeat; /* When hovered over */
}
.GoogleMarker:active {
    width: 1086px;
    height: 1118px;
    background: transparent url(button-2.png) 0 -1004px no-repeat; /* When you press down on the icon or the icon is activated (clicked on) */
}
```

Comment: Have you looked at the rendered page with chrome dev tools to see where the background image is?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a [jsfiddle file](http://jsfiddle.net/DEvhW/) on your issue, I made with a random image sprite I found on the Internet.

Set the `background-image` for the sprite just once, you don't need to repeat that more than once. From then on, the only thing you need to make sure is the correct `background-position` values. Every time you set the `background-image`, you are making another request for an image, even if you want to use the same one, and that is the main purpose we use image sprites - to avoid additional requests.

Comment: Im not good with html and css, so please the newbiness XD

Is this what you meant with the code? It still does the same thing :/
thanks for your help though :) 

.GoogleMarker {
    width: 1086px;
    height: 1118px;
    background: transparent url(button-2.png) 0 0px no-repeat; 
}
.GoogleMarker:hover {
    width: 1086px;
    height: 1118px;
    background-position: 0 -503px;
}
.GoogleMarker:active {
    width: 1086px;
    height: 1118px;
    background-position: 0 -1004px;
}

Comment: You don't need to specify `width` and `height` on your `:hover` and `:active` selectors. Check your image path, your console for any errors. If your button is an `<a>` element, make sure you add `display: block`. In other words copy-paste the code from the jsfiddle, replace the image URL and see if it behaves this way again.